# I'm looking into mining wikipedia change logs, but I'm not seeing a good way to go about it

Tags: data-mining, wikipedia

I'm looking into spelling errors and but first I need to establish a good process to mine the change logs. Unfortunately I'm not seeing a good way to view these logs or sort through many logs. Has anyone had any experience or know a good way to go about this?

Comment: What specific problem do you have that you need help with?

Comment: The OP said that they want to study spelling errors.  Presumably they are looking for article revisions which correct (or introduce?) spelling errors.

Comment: [mwdiffs](https://pythonhosted.org/mwdiffs/) and [wikiq](https://github.com/makoshark/wikiq) are supposed to help and were used for some interesting research.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make do with historical data (up to 2010), you could use Google's BigQuery on this public data set to look for revision comments which mention spelling corrections (e.g. typo, spell, etc): https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/publicdata:samples.wikipedia?pli=1

Relying on comments to self-identify spelling corrections is likely to miss a lot of stuff though, so the brute force way to do this is diff all the revisions and look at the diffs for patterns which match what you're looking for.  The dumps with all revisions begin `enwiki-latest-pages-meta-history` and are available in both bz2 and 7z format in the dump directory: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/. This a **lot** of data (ie 704 GB bz2 compressed, 108 GB 7z compressed, 15-20 TB uncompressed)

There's an (old) tutorial on using Hadoop with these dumps to analyze versions here: http://blog.mappian.com/hadoop/using-hadoop-to-analyze-the-full-wikipedia-dump-files-using-wikihadoop/

You might also want to review previous research which has been done in this area to see if there are tools that you could reuse, e.g. Wikipedia Revision Toolkit http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P11-4017 
https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-jwpl/